# How can I connect to FTP server in QT

Tags: c++, qt, ftp

I am trying to connect to a FTP server but I got the following issue :

> QObject::connect: No such slot  Object::replyFinished
>   in ...\ here my program name ......

Where is my mistake? I suppose it is in the following code :

```
///////////////Connection.h file////////

class Connection : public QObject 
{
 public:
     explicit Connection(QObject *parent=0);

     Connection(QString uri, QString usernmae, QString password);

     void FTP_Connection();  

     public slots:
         void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *);

    private:
        QString URI;
        QString USERNAME;
        QString PASSWORD;

       QNetworkAccessManager *manager;

   };  

  ///////////////Connection.cpp file////////
   Connection::Connection(QString uri, QString usernmae, QString password)
    {
       this->URI=uri;
       this->USERNAME=usernmae;
       this->PASSWORD=password;
    }
    void Connection::FTP_Connection()
    {
       QUrl url(this->URI);
       url.setUserName(this->USERNAME);
       url.setPassword(this->PASSWORD);
       url.setPort(21);

       QNetworkRequest request(url);

       manager=new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

      connect(manager,
              SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
              this,
              SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply *)));

             manager->get(request);
     } 
     ///////////////main.cpp file////////

      int main(int argc, char *argv[])
     {
        QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

        Connection *con=new Connection("ftp://192.168.3.62//",
                                       "win7",
                                       "053253");

        con->FTP_Connection();

        return a.exec();
        }
```

Comment: Any specific reason for not using QFtp class

Comment: Could you edit the title to reflect the actual problem you're having with connecting signals and slots? This doesn't seem to be specific to FTP.

Comment: You should add `Q_OBJECT` macro to your class I guess to use Qt connections.

Comment: if I add Q_OBJECT  it gives me error like  "Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall Connection::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@Connection@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ) C:\Users\Akmal\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Globe_Getter_Service_Background\Globe_Getter_Service_Background\Connection.obj
" any way thank you for answering

Comment: Re-run qmake after adding `Q_OBJECT`.